is_domain_same() causing the attribute error "'list' object has no attribute 'lower'"
I am trying to deploy a website, when deployed through Railway it works properly, but when I supply a custom domain and try to open the website it gives a 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' error.

Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py, line 133, in __call__
            response = self.process_request(request)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py, line 48, in process_request
        host = request.get_host()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/http/request.py, line 141, in get_host
        if domain and validate_host(domain, allowed_hosts):
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/http/request.py, line 732, in validate_host
    return any(
                 …
Local vars
/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/http/request.py, line 733, in <genexpr>
    Note: This function assumes that the given host is lowercased and has
    already had the port, if any, stripped off.
    Return ``True`` for a valid host, ``False`` otherwise.
    """
    return any(
        pattern == "*" or is_same_domain(host, pattern) for pattern in allowed_hosts
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
    )
def parse_accept_header(header):
    return [MediaType(token) for token in header.split(",") if token.strip()]
Local vars
/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/utils/http.py, line 235, in is_same_domain
    Any pattern beginning with a period matches a domain and all of its
    subdomains. (e.g. ``.example.com`` matches ``example.com`` and
    ``foo.example.com``). Anything else is an exact string match.
    """
    if not pattern:
        return False
    pattern = pattern.lower()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
    return (
        pattern[0] == "."
        and (host.endswith(pattern) or host == pattern[1:])
        or pattern == host
    )
Local vars

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? The allowed hosts is defined as ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['xyz.railway.app','127.0.0.1'] and that cause the error to be raised from is_domain_same()

Please show full error traceback

Well the error is pretty clear, pattern is a list, while .lower() need to be call on a string

sorry but cant understand which pattern, is_same_domain() is getting the allowed_hosts as parameter and both value in allowed hosts are string not list ,i tried '*' in allowed host  but it still not working
